# The arrayBuffer generated by the 3D model stl file occupies too much space, causing Safari to crash on the mobile end. How to solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, vtk, vtk.js

The arrayBuffer generated by the 3D model stl file occupies too much space, causing Safari to crash on the mobile end. How to solve this problem?
I use vtk.js to handle the display issue of stl files, use fetch to request stl files, return the result as arrayBuffer, and then use vtk.js's arrayBuffer parser to parse arrayBuffer data.
How should I handle it?

I try to request stl files one by one, also try to asynchronously request all files, and try to place fetch in webwork. After the request is completed, I send arrayBuffer data to the main thread, but the arrayBuffer is too large, A single stl file's arrayBuffer will have millions.
Use fetch streaming data? I'm not sure if vtk.js supports it?